# Does string concatenation in Swift make a new copy?

Tags: swift, string, string-concatenation

I can concatenate two strings in Swift like this:

`var c = "Hello World"
c += "!"`

Does this create a *new* string? (Allocating a new block of memory, copying over the original string, concatenating the "!" string and returning the new memory.) Or, does it update the original string in place (only allocating a new block of memory if the original block can't fit the character).

Comment: I think this comes under the heading of *"why do you care?"*.  It is an implementation detail that is subject to change.  You should assume that the Swift team will do *the right thing*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does not make a new copy. As you can see, the original string has changed.But the address remains same.

[image: string concatenation with memory address check]

Comment: What you print is the address of the `str` variable, and that does not change.  `str` is a `struct String` and that has (opaque) pointers to the character storage. Your output  does not tell anything about how the new character is actually appended to the string *storage.*

Comment: Even if it did for that to always be true a string would have to reserve a contiguous block of memory guaranteed to hold any possible future value, which is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

As it says in the apple documentation : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string

in the section of Performance optimizations:
"Although strings in Swift have value semantics, strings use a copy-on-write strategy to store their data in a buffer. This buffer can then be shared by different copies of a string. A string’s data is only copied lazily, upon mutation, when more than one string instance is using the same buffer. Therefore, the first in any sequence of mutating operations may cost O(n) time and space."

IOs use copy-on-write so if more than 1 process use the same variable, or has more than 1 copy (i don't fully understand this part), it makes a copy, but if the variable is only used for 1 process and has only one copy, then you can mutate it as you wish without generating copies